# Getting error while reading a Zip file of 70MB (NuGet extension Ionic.Zip)

Tags: c#, nuget, zip, nuget-package

I am able to unzip the files using the same code, but for the files above 65MB it is generating overflow error in **ZipFile.Read**

I have written the code:

```
using Ionic.Zip;

private void UnzipFile()
{
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(currentFilePath))
    {
        zip.ExtractAll(target_file_path, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    }
}
```

But getting overflow error:

```
Ionic.Zip.ZipException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Cannot read that as a ZipFile
  Source=Ionic.Zip
  StackTrace:
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.ReadIntoInstance(ZipFile zf)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(String fileName, TextWriter statusMessageWriter, Encoding encoding, EventHandler`1 readProgress)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(String fileName)

Inner Exception 1:
OverflowException: overflow while creating filename
```

Comment: There is a bug/issue report in a GitHub project related to Ionic.Zip: https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd/issues/101

Comment: But my file is not that much large as mentioned in the link you provided. The issue in your link has size of 4.7GB while my file size is just around 70MB. I have searched every aspect before writing the question actually.

Comment: So what? Does the ZIP file size being different prevent you from trying the workaround mentioned in that issue/bug report? (Did you notice in the bug report that the issue was not related to the file size apparently but a call count variable limiting number of (recursive?) AppendCopyToFileName calls artificially?)